# Debugging Issue

Tags: debugging, asp.net-2.0

I am not able to debug asp.net application in asp.net 2.0

Whenever I hit F5, it will wait for few minutes then show following message.

**Unable to start debugging on the web server. The operation has timed out.**

Edit: I also want to let you know that before posting this question I searched a lot on google and find out some key points like restart IIS, register asp.net.

What I was doing, I try to register aspnet_regiis -i by using standard console.
Now I find out that I need to execute vc 2005 command prompt which located under visual studio tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [restarting IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804040104/http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2006/04/11/74781.aspx)?  Also try and run the [application again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect?FeedbackID=202619) do you still get the error? And the classic, restart of windows.

With Visual Studio errors like this, you'll often find tons of information by searching on [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=unable%20to%20start%20debugging%20on%20the%20web%20server.%20The%20operation%20has%20timed%20out.&gws_rd=ssl), as unsatisfactory as that is, problems like this can originate from something as esoteric as a [third party software](https://ww1.devnewsgroups.net/).

Comment: @LFSR Consulting:
I did google, and find iis restart and reg iis, before posting this question. but the link you provided me. it give me a hint to register aspnet by using vs command line..

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, Is the port used by the Visual Studio Dev Web Server being used by some other Application?

Also try these [suggestions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=217429#tabs).